# Special relativity thought experiment

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

I'm trying to build some intuition to some basic concepts in Special Relativity. The following is a thought experiment from one of my lectures.

[image]

Here are the statements:

(1) According to Alice, her light signal reaches Charlie before the light signal sent by Bob.

(2) According to Alice, her light signal reaches Charlie at the same time as the light signal sent by Bob.

Here's my thought process:

- It's clear to me that one of the big points in Special Relativity is that light moves at the same speed in all inertial frames. So, both signals would hit Charlie at the same time.
- However, according to Alice it would perhaps be the case that her signal hits Bob first. In Alice's inertial frame, Charlie and Bob are moving at speed $-v$. However, due to their initial positioning, Bob is moving away from her and Charlie is moving towards her.
- However, what's immutable is that both light signals were emitted when Alice and Bob were at the same $x$ position. Therefore, according to Alice both signals hit Charlie at the same time. It doesn't matter if she's closer to Charlie by the time this happens.

Am I going wrong somewhere in my thinking?

Answer (score 3):

The light signals travel as a pair. They are emitted at the same time and place in every frame of reference (even non-inertial). Therefore both Alice and Bob will think that both signals reach Charlie at the same time. What will differ between Alice and Bob is how long they think that it takes for the signal pair to reach Charlie.

Thus, statement (2) is correct.

Answer (score -4):

Recall that special relativity introduces the notion of the spacetime interval, or the idea that the significant quantity relating the displacements in space and time between two events is invariant between reference frames. The way the problem is set up, we can immediately identify two points in spacetime: The point at which the signals are emitted (they occur at the same time and place for both observers, so they are the same spacetime point), and the point at which the signal is received.

If the second statement were true, then the time component of the spacetime interval for both observers would have to be the same, but since there is a relative velocity between their reference frames, this cannot be the case. Since Bob's spacetime interval has only a time component (since he stands still) but Alice moves through space and time, we can see that time component in Alice's frame will be smaller than in Bob's, since the space component has to account for some of the length of the spacetime interval, which is the same for both observers. This means that in her frame, the time separation between emission and reception will be smaller than that of Bob, and 
she will interpret her signal as being received before Bob's.

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely new to this topic so I have some trouble understanding you in some areas. Let me try and give a jist of what you're saying and you tell me where I'm wrong: both Alice and Bob emit a light signal at the exact same place and at the exact same time -- you cannot argue objectively that Charlie received the light beam first by any of them since that would imply one light beam was faster than another. However, once the light beam is emitted, I don't see how Alice's motion matters after this point, other than the fact that she will be closer to Charlie during reception.

Comment: Sort of. The whole idea of special relativity is that you can't argue *anything* objectively, except for the speed of light and the length of the spacetime interval between two events (also sometimes called the invariant interval, for that reason). Because Alice is moving with respect to Bob, she will perceive space and time differently than Bob will. It doesn't matter where she is during reception - just the very fact that she's moving means she is in a different reference frame, and therefore has different interpretations of the displacements in space and time between two events.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't covered spacetime intervals before, but from what I do understand, are you saying that since Alice is moving, the distance between her and Bob at emission is closer for her than it is for Bob? Even though they look to be the same distance away objectively? And this is because of length contraction?

Comment: Ah - if you haven't covered the spacetime interval yet then it may be confusing. Not quite - in fact, in her reference frame the length is longer than in Bob's. You need to toss out this idea of the way something is "objectively" - in special relativity, you always identify which observer is making an observation, and therefore nothing (except the speed of light and the length of the invariant interval) is objective.

Comment: As for your problem, consider this: whenever you solve time dilation problems in special relativity without using the invariant interval, you have to find the proper time. You would identify the proper time to be in Alice's frame, and the proper time is always the shortest time interval in any frame, and since Bob is in a different frame than Alice, you know his time is longer.

Comment: No objectivity except spacetime interval and speed of light. Understood. I can agree with you on the proper time interval, but indulge me with this: say I make a spacetime diagram to describe this, in Alice's frame. This means I center her at $x=0$ with a straight line. Therefore, Charlie and Bob move at some slanted $-x$ line. Bob and Alice both emit light at some time, and, the same position I take it. Thus, Bob's worldline has a $y$ intercept at $x=0$. And since they're at the same position when they emit the light, the light cones they emit hit Charlie simultaneously they basically overlap

Comment: So how can I illustrate this with a spacetime diagram? Just to repeat for clarity -- both emit light at the same space and time coordinates, so their light cones should pretty much be right on top of eachother, even though Bob's worldline is slanted and so is Charlie's. Am I picturing this wrong? Where am I getting this twisted?

Comment: Remember in a spacetime diagram, when you "shift" into another reference frame, the axes slant. The light cones are the same, but have different intercepts with Alice's and Bob's axes,so they perceive it differently. Since Bob and Charlie are moving in the -x direction with respect to Alice, the axes move in the opposite direction, and would look like the right diagram in this image: https://properphysics.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/sr7.png

Comment: Interesting. Two things: (a) Is my approach then to draw my light cones such that they are $45 \ degree$ and $-45 \ degree$ from either $t$ line? Then I can show that Alice's light cone will hit Charlie's world line at a smaller $t$. (b) Why is the $t$ line for the slanted $x$ not orthogonal to it?

Comment: The actual angle that the axes will bend will depend on Alice's velocity.

Comment: Hmm. Is my interpretation for (a) somewhat correct?

Comment: You are wrong. The light signals travel as a pair. Therefore both Alice and Bob will think that both signals reach Charlie at the same time. What will differ between Alice and Bob is how long they think that it takes for the signal pair to reach Charlie.